# use of join sql command

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables- Gadgets and Usage. Gadgets have a Unique ID and the corresponding fields. Whereas the Usage shows the usage like old and new ID values of Gadgets.

```
Gadgets TABLE
         ID  &  gadgetName

USAGE TABLE
     oldID & newID
```

Now i want to map between them with an input = gadgetName
Like let the fields be like

```
 Gadgets 

 ID   gadgetName
 +++ ++++++++++++
 id1    nokia
 id2    motog
 id3    xiamoi
 id4    micromax
```

And the Usage table is like

```
Usage Table

oldID   newID
+++++   ++++++
 id1     id2
 id2     id3
 id3     id4
 id2     id4
```

Now, with the input as micromax , i want to retrieve the gadgetName from gadget Table which was present in the oldID for which the newID was micromax.

Like the o/p is :

```
oldIDgadgetName
++++++++++++++++
xiamoi 
motog
```

### EDIT:

I tried this :

```
SELECT gadgets.gadgetName, gadgets.ID FROM usage, gadgets 
WHERE  usage.oldID IN ( 
   SELECT usage.oldID FROM usage , gadgets 
   WHERE usage.newID = gadgets.ID AND gadgets.gadgetName= ".$datawon."
 )" );
```

& iam not getting the desired output...
.
 i would like to apply join here..please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to join the Gadget table twice:

```
select g2.gadgetName as oldIDgadgetName
from Gadgets g1
join Usage u on g1.ID = u.newID
join Gadgets g2 on g2.ID = u.oldID
where g1.gadgetName = 'micromax'
```

Given your sample data this would return:

```
oldIDgadgetName
---------------
motog
xiamoi
```

This can also be written without joins altogether (but it might perform worse) like this:

```
select gadgetName 
from Gadgets 
where id in (
    select oldid 
    from Usage 
    where newID in (
       select id 
       from Gadgets 
       where gadgetName = 'micromax'
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks...can u please tell me what was wrong in my query as given in the EDIT

Comment: @SyamiliV Two errors in your query: `gadgets.gadgets = ".$datawon."` should be `gadgets.gadgetname = ".$datawon."` (and you might need to quote the variable too, looks like your injecting it with php maybe?) and also you were missing the join in the outer query: `AND usage.newID = gadgets.ID` at the end.

Comment: thanks, i just corrected the variable name... the second one is true, its a php variable iam using.  can this condition be handled without using join ..

Comment: @SyamiliV Yes, it can be written without joins, I've updated the answer to show how.

Comment: i tried the query ina sqllfiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d68d7/1) . can u please help me what is wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Try using join and using joined result as a subquery to fetch the gadget names like:

```
SELECT gadgetName
FROM Gadgets WHERE id in (
     SELECT u.oldId
     FROM Gadgets g INNER JOIN usage u 
     ON g.id = u.newId
     WHERE g.gadgetName = 'micromax')
```

Inner query is going to return you old id of micromax by joining id on newId in other usage table and then using those oldId you do lookup in your gadgets table for name. You could even do it by joining on Gadgets table twice.

Comment: thanks..it worked, can u please tell me what was wrong in my query as given in the EDIT

Comment: In your case, you are doing exactly the same as mine inner sub query but see your outer query, you are again trying to join on gadget and usage which is not needed and in addition, you havent provided the join condition as well and this join is not needed as well.

Comment: so can this condition be applied only using join...iam now curious , if there any way we can bring the data without using join. ( Hey, is join faster than using multiple queries ?)

Comment: @SyamiliV The only issue I saw in the fiddle is that you have to run the query in the right window: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/907987/1

Comment: @jpw thanks. Yeah Syamili please use run SQL button and you will see the result at bottom of your screen.